# I am confused about Liouville Theorem with a function seemingly disproving it. Please help me explain!

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex function $f(z) = \sin{z}.$ It is analytic and bounded (max $|f(z)| = 1$). However, it's not constant. This seems to disprove Liouville's Theorem. What did I go wrong here?

Comment: bounded when $z$ is in the real line. When $z$ is pure imaginary, say $z=it$ for real $t,$ it is $ i \sinh t$

Comment: $|\sin(i)|=1.17\ldots$

Comment: $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$

Comment: Good catch.   This is an important insight.   The complex sin is not bounded.